# Adding extra left margin in pdf print without using Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I want to print out a large review article, available as a pdf, with an extra 1" left margin to facilitate getting it bound. I've heard it happens naturally in Acrobat Pro, but I don't have it and am not inclined to dish out the license fee since I don't imagine using it for anything else.

In the reader, you can only scale it by an overall percentage, which is undesirable since that would reduce the font size. I only want to increase the left margin.

So, is there any way to do this **legally** and free of cost (i.e. without buying any software)?

As ''sufficient prior research'', I scanned through the existing questions, and while there are many that caress this point, I found the intentions in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/289174/add-margins-to-pdf-generated-via-printing-in-safari) closest. However, I am a windows user, and am printing an existing pdf file, so it doesn't address my concern.

I'm sorry if this happens to be a duplicate of a question that I could not find :)

Answer (score 1):

What you may try out is defining a custom paper size in the print dialog. With the according setting of the placement of the page, you should then be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Print&Share in the past to individually set printer margins. It is not free as you requested but could maybe help you.

[image: Ricoh Print&Share printer margins]

**Update**: I've just seen that you can change unit of measure in the General settings to Inch.

Comment: Not free, sure, but helpful indeed. But hopefully, some day, someone will suggest some free work-around too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your (advanced) printer settings. Depending on the model and drivers, you might be able to simply tick a checkbox or use a dropdown field to enable the binding margin on either side.

E.g. for my HP Officejet printer there are two related settings: One allowing you to enable double-sided printing, the other to pick the margin's position (left or right).

This will automatically downscale your content or rearrange the layout (only if needed; again, might depend on a setting), to properly fit the pages, without you having to toy around with fake page sizes etc.

---

You may also try to actually edit the PDF using the tool suggested in the question linked by you (which is indeed essentially a duplicate). Just have a look at [feklee's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/289174/add-margins-to-pdf-generated-via-printing-in-safari#380869). Even though the initial question has been aiming at MacOS X, this answer should work cross-platform.

It might be a bit tricky to get it to work (installing dependencies and such), but overall it might be the most general approach to this problem.

Comment: Yes the tick-box thing is an option (I'm clueless about the other suggestion), but suppose if I want to a generate a pdf itself with these pseudo-margins, so that I can just hit Ctrl+P and get an o/p. (This ain't a fake example, I don't carry my printer everywhere. Sometimes, you ask someone else to take a printout of your file, and don't want to leave the margins to his/her intellect). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So you want to have the margins embedded into the file? Then yes, the second option is one way to go, but I'm not too deep into that topic either. :)

Answer (score 0):

A 1 year late answer, However, there is a free utility to do so
PDFill PDF tools utility, you can choose reformat pages and you will see a bunch of customizations including page margins!. You might need to get used to how it works and try a few times before you get what you want though, nevertheless, it's a great program.